# Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00' for function str_to_date

Tags: mysql, triggers, str-to-date

I'm trying to change the format of a date from a CSV file before insert. I created a trigger BEFORE INSERT but it doesn't seem to work.

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  item_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  price_list_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  sku varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  description varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  cost float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  notes varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  discount_factor float DEFAULT '1',
  start_date date DEFAULT NULL,
  end_date date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (item_id,sku),
  KEY price_list_id_idx (price_list_id),
  CONSTRAINT price_list_id FOREIGN KEY (price_list_id) REFERENCES price_lists (price_list_id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=105193 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is my trigger BEFORE INSERT

```
CREATE TRIGGER `pricelist`.`items_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `items` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.start_date = str_to_date(NEW.start_date, '%c/%e/%Y');
    SET NEW.end_date = str_to_date(NEW.end_date, '%c/%e/%Y');

END
```

Let say the query is : `INSERT IGNORE INTO pricelist.items (price_list_id, sku, description, cost, start_date, end_date, notes) VALUES ('15', '2494-22', 'M12 DRILL/IMPACT COMBO KIT', '129', '4/25/2016', '5/31/2016', 'CL6204');`

I get this error :

```
`Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00' for function str_to_date`
```

If i do (without IGNORE):

```
INSERT INTO pricelist.items (price_list_id, sku, description, cost, start_date, end_date, notes) VALUES ('15', '2494-22', 'M12 DRILL/IMPACT COMBO KIT', '129', '4/25/2016', '5/31/2016', 'CL6204');
```

I get this :

```
Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: '4/25/2016' for column 'start_date' at row 1
```

Although this works :

```
SELECT str_to_date('5/31/2016', '%c/%e/%Y');
```

The output is :

```
2016-05-31
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it has something to do with your default null on your dates in the table.

Comment: Obviously, datetime value is wrong.

Comment: @RichardBarker I'll try to remove it to see.

Comment: I think you're sending in the wrong value to str_to_date. It looks like you're using the row currently being inserted and not the values passed to the insert statement... But I could be wrong.

Comment: `the row currently be inserted and not the values passed to the insert statement` ... aren't these the same thing?

Comment: Are they? I'd think not from MySQL's point of view.

Comment: I read the documentation and that's what they were doing. New.columnname is the value that is going to be inserted in the "columnname"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are gettting this error because you are trying to insert a `date` column which is of the wrong format.  The [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html) lists the formats which are acceptable:

> MySQL recognizes DATE values in these formats:
>
> As a string in either 'YYYY-MM-DD' or 'YY-MM-DD' format. A “relaxed” syntax is permitted: Any punctuation character may be used as the delimiter between date parts. For example, '2012-12-31', '2012/12/31', '2012^12^31', and '2012@12@31' are equivalent.
>
> As a string with no delimiters in either 'YYYYMMDD' or 'YYMMDD' format, provided that the string makes sense as a date.
>
> As a number in either YYYYMMDD or YYMMDD format, provided that the number makes sense as a date.

But your date has the format `MM/DD/YYYY`, e.g. `4/25/2016`, so this won't work.  It appears you were attempting to use a trigger to correct the format before the insert.  However, MySQL checks the formatting *before* the trigger is even hit.

If you must insert date data with this format then you should do so using a `VARCHAR` type and then call `STR_TO_DATE` afterwards.  Or, you should clean up the formatting of your dates to match one of the acceptable formats.

Comment: Seems to be a correct answer, I thought maybe BEFORE INSERT Trigger would have been a solution.. I'll try to find another solution, thanks.

Comment: So the select statement at the end of the question fails then?

Comment: You were clever to try to use `BEFORE INSERT` but MySQL still has a restriction on the format of `date`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think I'll change it do varchar and call it a day. :P

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks a lot! deleted the old row, created new one's with varchar and my trigger does the right formatting!